# Adding role to Identity programmatically

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-5, class-library

Before every thing I should say: "**Why things that used to be easy have become so difficult now!!!!**"

I create a `Class Library` project for my EF data context. I want to use `Identity` too. So I create context class like this:

```
public class Context : IdentityDbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=.;Database=MyDB1;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
}
```

and I add migration and update database. So I want to write some code to add a role to role table and use : `RoleManager<IdentityRole>` :

```
private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _rolesManager;

public RoleRepository()
{
    _rolesManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>();
}

public async Task AddRole(string roleName)
{
    var role = new IdentityRole();
    role.Name = roleName;
    await _roleManager.CreateAsync(role);
}
```

the problem is I can't instantiate from `RoleManager<IdentityRole>` and I get this error:

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'store' of 'RoleManager.RoleManager(IRoleStore, IEnumerable<IRoleValidator>, ILookupNormalizer, IdentityErrorDescriber, ILogger<RoleManager>)'

How can I add this parmaters when instantiate from `RoleManager<IdentityRole>`?

How can I add role To Role table in a class library project?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope below code might help you.

```
using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
          {
            var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context), null, null, null, null);

            var role = new IdentityRole(RoleName);

            var result = await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(RoleName);
            if (!result)
            {
              await roleManager.CreateAsync(role);
            }
          }
```

Comment: Sorry it didn't work

Comment: Are you still getting the same error with that change?

Comment: I edited your answer

Comment: I'm glad it worked. thank you.